# Shape of graph and plot

Tags: graphing-functions

Suppose $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $y \in [-1,1]$. When we plot $y$ vs. $x$, we get an upward parabola shape. Suppose we plot $y^2$ vs. $x$. Would the shape also be approximately an upward parabola?